# Unity спамит ошибку AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found

Tags: c#, unity3d, build-error

Я смотрел много ответов в интернете, не один не помог.

Ошибка:

```
AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon (System.String name, System.Int32 genericParameterCount, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConv, System.Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConv, System.Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
System.Type.GetMethod (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
System.Type.GetMethod (System.String name) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
GooglePlayServices.UnityCompat.GetUnity56AndAboveApplicationIdentifier (UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/UnityCompat.cs:446)
GooglePlayServices.UnityCompat.GetApplicationId (UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/UnityCompat.cs:500)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.GetAndroidApplicationId () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1043)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver+PropertyPoller`1[T].Poll (System.Func`1[TResult] getCurrentValue, GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver+PropertyPoller`1+Changed[T] changed) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:343)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.PollBundleId () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1431)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at <e0956a95eb034b1e8f26f24b08543746>:0)
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: удалось разобраться?

Comment: да, нужно создать новый проект на версии unity ниже 2021.2 и перекинуть в него все файлы того проекта. Но ассеты лучше переустановить а не перекидывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why do I get Error: Ambiguous Match Found (Non-Mediation PSR in use)?](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408586248340-Why-do-I-get-Error-Ambiguous-Match-Found-Non-Mediation-PSR-in-use-)

**Вольный перевод на русский содержимого по ссылке:**

В Unity Editor, если вы видите такое выброшенное исключение в консоли:

```
AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon (System.String name, System.Int32 genericParameterCount, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConv, System.Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) (at <316d36b1472c4d88ab1721a02433c966>:0)
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConv, System.Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) (at <316d36b1472c4d88ab1721a02433c966>:0)
System.Type.GetMethod (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) (at <316d36b1472c4d88ab1721a02433c966>:0)
System.Type.GetMethod (System.String name) (at <316d36b1472c4d88ab1721a02433c966>:0)
GooglePlayServices.UnityCompat.GetUnity56AndAboveApplicationIdentifier (UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/UnityCompat.cs:357)
```

Эта ошибка может возникать, если вы используете более новую версию Unity Editor (2021.2, 2022+), а так же:

- Верcию PlayServicesResolver, которая была установлена со старой версией Mediation (0.1.1 и ниже)
- Версия PlayServicesResolver установлена не вместе с Mediation

Чтобы исправить ошибку, выполните следующее:

1. Обновитесь до Unity Mediation SDK 0.2.0 или новее, затем закройте проект.
2. Удалите **Assets/PlayServicesResolver** каталог в вашем проекте.
3. Откройте проект заново, и вы должны увидеть приглашение установить PlayServicesResolver (версия предоставляется вместе с пакетом Mediation). Установите эту версию PlayServicesResolver.

Больше информации можно найти в документации [Unity Mediation](https://docs.unity.com/mediation/Content/IntroToMediation.htm).